# If column doesn't have any value greater than 1 then exit

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an IF statement that does the following:

1. highlights (with red color) anything with a value greater than 1 and less than 26, and then continue with the rest of the macro and do other things **(which I've successfully done)**.
2. if there's a value over 25, then highlight with red, produce a messagebox, and exitsub **(which I've successfully done)**.
3. if ALL rows are = 1, then do nothing and exit sub **(which i'm struggling with)**.

[image]

```
For Each C In Range("B2:B25000").Cells
  If C.Value > 1 And C.Value < 26 Then
    firstValue = C.Value
    firstAddress = C.Address
    Exit For
    
    If Not (C.Value > 1 And C.Value < 26) Then Exit Sub 'No
  
    ElseIf C.Value > 25 Then
    C.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbRed
    MsgBox "Too big!"
    Exit Sub
  End If
Next

C.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbRed 'if greater than 1 & less than 26 then Color = red

'remaining of the macro goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: use `WorksheetFunction.CountA` and `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` (counting ones), and check if they're equal. Or just `Countif` for `<>1`.

Comment: Also point 1 and 2 can be handled via conditonal formatting. No need for VBA?

Comment: @SiddharthRout it seems like that but in my case i need a VBA, because it's highlight red & then do many other things

Comment: Just saw your edits. Since you have managed the first 2 points, did you see what @BigBen suggested above?

Comment: Another way to check for 3rd condition is `If ws.evaluate("AND(EXACT(B2:B25000,B2),(B2=1))") = True Then` where `ws` is the relevant worksheet

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout I didn't understand what BigBen suggested yet, regarding your what you suggested it's giving me a debug error 424

Comment: Did you declare ws?

Comment: @SiddharthRout No but i replaced it with the full destination - If Workbooks("excel_file.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cell.Evaluate("AND(EXACT(B2:B25000,B2),(B2=1))") = True Then Exit Sub

Comment: Delete `.Cell`. Try this `If Workbooks("excel_file.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Evaluate("AND(EXACT(B2:B25000,B2),(B2=1))") = True Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout but still didn't work. it's giving me a 424 error

Comment: That is an object required error. That means the problem is with `Workbooks("excel_file.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1")`. Can you declare a workbook and worksheet object and then init them. Some thing like `Dim wb as workbook` and then `Set wb = Workbooks("excel_file.xlsm")` and similarly `Dim ws as worksheet` and then `Set ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")` and finally `If ws.evaluate("AND(EXACT(B2:B25000,B2),(B2=1))") = True Then`

Comment: "if ALL rows are = 1, then do nothing and exit sub" You don't mean all 24,999 rows do you ?

Comment: @CDP1802 no i mean only the ones that have values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this
`If Not (C.Value > 1 And C.Value < 26) Then Exit Sub`

with this `ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("b:b")) = 1 Then Exit Sub`

and it worked perfect

Comment: Note this will also exit if one or more of the values is less than 1 ie a zero. Perhaps `Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("b:b")) = 1 and Application.WorksheetFunction.min(Range("b:b")) = 1 then Exit  Sub`

Comment: yes you are correct, but the data will never contain 0 values @CDP1802

Answer (score 1):

Use the if statements to set logic flags and then decide whether to exit sub or continue.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, lastrow As Long
    Dim bAllOnes As Boolean, bTooBig As Boolean
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    bAllOnes = True
    bTooBig = False
    
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In ws.Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Cells
        If Val(c.Value) > 1 Then
            bAllOnes = False
            c.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbRed
            If c.Value > 25 Then
                 bTooBig = True
            End If
        ElseIf Val(c.Value) < 1 Then
            bAllOnes = False
        End If
    Next
    
    If bTooBig Then
        MsgBox "Too big!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf bAllOnes Then
        MsgBox "All 1's!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Continueing"
    End If
    
End Sub
```